# Failed upload to aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

I am running the following script. (intentionally i hide the keys of course).
It is basically a copy paste from the `readme.md`.

Enviroment details:
 - I have windows 10.
 - running this script on git bash enviroment.
 - docker version is 18.03.1-ce

`docker container run \
--env AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=aaaaaaa \
--env AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=bbbbbbb \
-v $PWD:/data \
garland/aws-cli-docker \
aws s3 sync . s3://www.typing-coacher.net`

i am getting the following error:

`C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Mount denied:
The source path "C:/projects/docker;C"
doesn't exist and is not known to Docker.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.`

the folder path that actually exist is: `C:/projects/docker`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Git Bash environment will evaluate `$PWD` to `/c/projects/docker` instead of `C:\projects\docker`. Docker daemon will not be able to find that path.

Walkarounds:

1. Use Winodows shell or PowerShell.
2. Use absolute path instead of `$PWD`.